# cancelling a observable with takeUntil not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an autocomplete HTTP call and an execute search HTTP call... I need the autocomplete call to abort when the execute action is triggered.  What I am doing right now is using a Subject like so:

```
private onExecute$ = new Subject();
```

In my autocomplete method:

```
executeAutoComplete(e) {
  this.myService.searchAutoComplete(e.criteria)
  .pipe(
   takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
   takeUntil(this.onExecute$),
   map( 
  // continue with more code
```

Then in my execute method I raise the signal:

```
executeSearch(e) {
console.log('triggering onExecute signal');
this.onExecute$.next();
  // other code
}
```

so in my console I see 'triggering onExecute signal' but the autocomplete results return AFTER the full search starts executing, I thought that once I raise the signal the takeUntil will abort the chain?  It does not work.

So essentially the behavior I am trying to prevent is that the autocomplete results should not return and open the drop down when a search is triggered by the user since it's no longer relevant.

What am I missing here?

Edit -

the order is infact the issue due to the debounce time the execute is always called before autocomplete, order can be unpredictable anways.  Did not realize that the onExecute.next() will be lost if the Observable chain is not yet active.

I do have a searchLoading variable that is also set, how can I use this?

I tried:

```
takeUntil(Observable.of(this.searchLoading))
```

This does not work as it's always true!  how do I use takeUntil with a boolean value that is evaluated dynamically?

Edit 2 -

Got it using takeWhile instead:

```
takeWhile(() => !this.searchLoading))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that `executeSearch` is called before `executeAutoComplete`? If `onExecute$` has already emitted a value before the observable chain is constructed that won't stop the search from executing.

By the way: it seems to me that it would be simpler to call `unsubscribe` on the subscription when you run the search.

Comment: you can use a variable (takeUntil(()=>this.alive) and toggle the variable this.alive to true anywhere. I am not sure that this.onDestroy$ becomes false anytime

Comment: will check the order... the change event is emitted to the parent by the child component when the user enters text, the execute event is emitted when the user hits the Enter key or clicks on the search icon, technically the change event (autocomplete) should be emitted before the enter key (execute) because that's the sequence of user actions but it may not be necessarily in that order... there is a debounce of 400ms on the change so that may be causing the issue!

Comment: I added a comment to my original question regarding this, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is old but i had the same cenario.

If you want to use takeUntil, the correct Subject is ReplaySubject.

- Because if Subject emits anything before takeUntil call, it will not reemit when takeUntil subscribes to Subject(as implementation do), and  takeUntil will not unsubscribe the source.
- On the other way, ReplaySubject reemits on subscription, so takeUntil will cancel with it internal unsubscribe call.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news is, it works.

I've been trying to find a flaw using this approximation of your code, but unfortunately cannot.
I post it here in case it's useful to someone.

```js
console.clear()

const takeUntil = Rx.operators.takeUntil;

const onDestroy$ = new Rx.Subject();
const onExecute$ = new Rx.Subject();

const source$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0,1000)
const executeAt$ = Rx.Observable.timer(3000)

executeAt$
  .subscribe(x => {
     console.log('execute');
     onExecute$.next(); 
   })

source$
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(onDestroy$), 
    takeUntil(onExecute$)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

On the subject of `unsubscribe()` vs `takeUntil()`, in ['Don't Unsubscribe'](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) Ben Lesh says

> Keeping too many subscription objects around is a sign you’re managing your subscriptions imperatively, and not taking advantage of the power of Rx.

and

> Compose your subscription management with takeUntil

---

**Footnote - Service Instances**

Given that the Rx code looks ok, another possible cause is multiple instances of an Angular service.

If `private onExecute$ = new Subject();` is wrapped in a service, and you have that service in two provide arrays (say in a module + a component, or in two components), then the instance you call `.next()` on may be different to the instance used in the `takeUntil()`.

It's a long-shot, and your code above indicates it's not the case, but seems to be quite a common occurrence.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, since the concept works (like I thought it should) let me look more closely at the code, perhaps i'm missing something somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in `this.destroy$.complete();`
I was using subscription in service which was invoked in many components. And I was trying to to stop the subscription in service from component OnDestroy hook by calling service method:

```
destroySubscriptions() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

But after the first component has stop the subscription and complete `destroy$` Subject, the next component cannot stop the subscription in service because the  `destroy$` Subject was already completed and the `this.destroy$.next();` do not take any actions. So be careful by completing the Subject, it will not work any more. Such an ambiguous stuff : )